# why this while loop exit but execute the inside code?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, nan

I got this code working properly if I enter a number, whenever I enter the string "end" it should get out the while loop without executing the code.

But if I enter "end" I get total: NaN ended , why?

I'd like to get the total of the numbers I entered.

```
var i = 1;
var totale = 0;
var index = Array();
var domanda = 0;

while (!isNaN(domanda)) {
    domanda = prompt("Write a number, the total so far is: " + totale);
    index[i] = Number(domanda);
    totale += index[i];
    i++;
}

document.writeln("total: " + totale);
document.writeln("ended");
```

Comment: You need to check for isNaN after you get the input and if isNaN break.

Answer (score 0):

Check for NaN right after input.

```
var i=1;
var totale = 0;
var index = Array();
var domanda = 0;

while (true) {
   domanda = prompt("Write a number, the total so far is: "+totale);
      if(isNaN(domanda)) {
         break;   
      }
   index[i]=Number(domanda);
   totale += index[i];
   i++;
}

document.writeln("total: " + totale);

document.writeln("ended");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop checks whether `domanda` is not a number. *Then*, you have the user enter a new value for `domanda`, which might be *end*. *Then*, you add that value to your total - making `total` not a number, either, if `domanda` is not a number.

Your `while` loop can only stop in the line that starts with `while`. If the condition changes somewhere in the loop body, that iteration will still completely be executed before the loop condition is checked for the next time, and the loop gets aborted.

A straightforward way to change this here is to add another check right *after* `domanda` has been changed:

```
while (!isNaN(domanda)) {
    domanda = prompt("Write a number, the total so far is: "+totale);
    if (isNaN(domanda)) {
        break;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: @passegua: If the answer solved your problem, please select is as accepted, to express towards all future visitors that the problem has been solved. If it was otherwise helpful, please consider upvoting it.